# OpenVPN traffic with Synology not encrypted?

Tags: networking, vpn, encryption, openvpn, synology

**Requested:** I would like to have the possibility to encrypt my internet traffic from my portable computer when I'm on networks outside my home. From what I have understood, this should be possible using a VPN connection.

**What I tried:** I have a Synology NAS, and I have set up the VPN server. I configured the OpenVNP and exported the certificate an installed the OpenVPN GUI on my portable. My portable has no problems connecting to the VPN.
I then went looking on the web how to check if your traffic gets encrypted. Came across a program called Wireshark. Installed it and tested it with a http website. The website came up in the results, I could read the url.

**What I would like to know:** Do I need to change some settings on either the portable or the VPN Server in order to get my traffic encrypted? Or is this not even possible?

Thank you in advance.

*portable runs on Win 8.1 Pro 64bit, Synology is on latest 5.1-5022 update 2 DSM.

Comment: The Website you Werke visiti

Comment: the Website you were visiting does not use the VPN connection

Answer (score 1):

Wireshark might be hooked in before the data is pushed into the tunnel where it's encrypted. To test it properly you might need to try have a look from a computer other than the one connected to the VPN.